# Can Before Insert Trigger pass null value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, null, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have a before insert trigger and I'm trying to define it to insert values, and null values when necessary.

I'm trying something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  InsertPrezimeRuk
BEFORE INSERT ON RADNICI
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
I_novo_pr varchar2(50);
BEGIN
 SELECT prezime INTO I_novo_pr 
   FROM RADNICI
   WHERE jmbg= :new.ruk_jmbg;
   :new.prezime_rukovodioca:= I_novo_pr;
END;
```

And when I try to insert some null values it returns error that no data is found.

But I want to set this, when no data is discovered to simply pass a null value into the table.
And I tried something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  InsertPrezimeRuk
BEFORE INSERT ON RADNICI
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
I_novo_pr varchar2(50);
BEGIN
IF I_novo_pr is null
THEN :new.prezime_rukovodioca:= null;
END IF; 
 SELECT prezime INTO I_novo_pr 
   FROM RADNICI
   WHERE jmbg= :new.ruk_jmbg;
   :new.prezime_rukovodioca:= I_novo_pr;
END;
```

But it's still not working.

Is this possible at all? If it is, please help.

Comment: I_novo_pr is always null in the 2nd trigger.

Comment: 2nd trigger is not working I tried it that way, the point is that, I_novo_pr sometimes could contain null values, and I want it to pass that null values into table instead of giving me an error that no data is found

Comment: Sounds like you just need an exception block in your first trigger to handle no_data_found errors. Out of curiosity, is `jmbg` a unique column? If not, then what happens if there's more than one row returned by your query? You need to cater for the too_many_rows error as well.

Comment: Yes jmbg is primary key in table RADNICI, but ruk_jmbg column can be sometimes a null value. Problem is I don't know how to set that exception block

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  InsertPrezimeRuk
BEFORE INSERT ON RADNICI
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
I_novo_pr varchar2(50);
BEGIN
 SELECT prezime INTO I_novo_pr 
   FROM RADNICI
   WHERE jmbg= :new.ruk_jmbg;
   :new.prezime_rukovodioca:= I_novo_pr;
exception
   when no_data_found then  :new.prezime_rukovodioca:=null;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working perfeclty!! I just didn't encountered with this exception when no_data_found action untill now